# How to resize dynamic images coming from database in a responsive bootstrap website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using yslow in which it tells don't scale images in HTML but the images are coming from database and I use them using bootstrap grids. Most of the images are show in popup on click.

The image width I set is in the css file in percentages like `max-width:100%` or `width:100%;`, but I don't know what to set to not scale the images in HTML.

I don't know how to resolve this issue. Please help me.

Comment: It's not a big deal (in my opinion), if your images are not that big in size don't worry about it. Because, really, you have to get the image size based on user device and insert the resized photo into your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YSlow is telling you this because it is not a good practice to resize images in HTML, especially if the images become smaller, as this means you spend too much time downloading.

You don't need to take everything performance monitors like YSlow are telling you as an action item. The reports are only recommendations. As @Amin Gharavi said, if the images load fast enough for you, then it's probably okay.

The problem is if you are downloading images that are MUCH bigger than their apparent visual, which usually means much slower download in addition to lower visual quality in some browsers.

Comment: I give the access to the admin to upload images so it is not in my hand how big or small images he/she uploads that's the main reason i ask this question while loading website first time slower.Next time it takes the images from cache.

Comment: You can do what infrastructures like WordPress are doing, and once an image is uploaded, several copies of it in various sizes are created automatically. Then the server chooses the best one (or use the experimental PICTURE tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)